# How do I Resize entire screen?

Tags: directx, resize

I want to be able to re size everything that is displayed - taskbar, windows, desktop - everything and put it in a border.  What is the best way to accomplish this?  I'm thinking DirectX, but I am not that familiar with it. I'm not sure what technologies would accomplish this, but I bet it would have to be rather low level.

Comment: wasn't clear what OS you were referring to

Answer (score 1):

DirectX has its own API's, but if you want to change the taskbar and desktop, I rather think you have to go for the Windows API.

The direct API call to use is [ChangeDisplaySettings()](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/ChangeDisplaySettings.html) or [ChangeDisplaySettingsEx()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183413(VS.85).aspx), but you need to get a filled-in [DEVMODE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183565(VS.85).aspx) structure to use it properly. DEVMODE is a beast. You're going to need to fill it using [EnumDisplaySettings()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162611(VS.85).aspx), identify which display is your main screen, and fiddle with the dmBitsPerPel, dmPelWidth, and dmEplHeight members. Not every possible setting is supported: I think [DeviceCapabilities()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183552(VS.85).aspx) can tell you that... this should get you started.

You haven't told us explicitly that it's Windows you're after, nor in what language you're working.